# android wear: only picture, no title second page

Tags: android, bitmap, android-notifications, wear-os

I created a second page for android wear. That page should only contain a bitmap.

With the following code, the bitmap shows up nicely, but I also get a title line. Even if the title is empty.

```
// Create second page notification
Notification secondPageNotification =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(map))
        .build();
```

Ho can I get rid of that title field/line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
.extend(new WearableExtender().setHintShowBackgroundOnly(true));
```

This will hide a card and leave only a background:)
More info: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.WearableExtender.html#setHintShowBackgroundOnly(boolean)).

Your final code should look like this:

```
Notification secondPageNotification =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(map))
    .extend(new WearableExtender().setHintShowBackgroundOnly(true));
    .build();
```

Comment: Excellent. Guess you meant `getHintShowBackgroundOnly(true)`. Works with that.

Comment: Grrr. setHintShowBackgroundOnly(true)

Comment: Haha. Yes, sorry. I've copied the wrong docs link by mistake and then copied from link:) I've edited my answer. Please tell if it works for you :)

Comment: Yes. Works like a charm.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt: If this answer solved your problems please accept it (you can also upvote if it was helpful to you). This will help other people to find a solution to similar problems:)

Comment: I'd love to. But how?

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt accespting answers is a basic rule on StackOverflow. You need to click the "tick" http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png to accept, and up arrow to upvote. You should do that in your every question, when you got a correct answer to your problem.

Comment: More than happy to do that. And I did. :-) I wanted to do that before, but did not find the tick...